# Shift field values

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53ebc91c5b8bb46c9683b022"),
    "tagid" : "tag1",
    "location1" : "shelf1",
    "location2" : "shelf2",
    "location3" : "shelf3",
    "location4" : "shelf4",
    "location5" : "shelf5",
}
```

And a function:

```
def myfunction():
    loc1 = {"location1": request.form.get('location')}
    query = {"tagid": request.form.get('tag')}
    tagid = handle.trackingdb.update(query,{"$set": loc1},**{'upsert':True})
```

If myfunction gets a new location (shelfz), how can I efficiently insert it into location1, while shifting the other field values down so it looks like it is below while keeping the fields to just the 5 locations?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53ebc91c5b8bb46c9683b022"),
    "tagid" : "tag1",
    "location1" : "shelfz",
    "location2" : "shelf1",
    "location3" : "shelf2",
    "location4" : "shelf3",
    "location5" : "shelf4",
}
```

My current thought approach is:

```
query tagid
copy location4 to location5
copy location3 to location4
copy location2 to location3
copy location1 to location2
insert location1
```

However I'm not sure how to express this with PyMongo or if it is even a practical way of accomplishing the task.

Comment: Keeping all five values as dictionary key:value pairs is absolutely the wrong way to go. What you want is a queue. https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque

Comment: Or in MongoDB terms this would be an "array". Dictionary/hash/Map things where "keys" store a "data point" is an anti-pattern. Values are meant to store values and not keys, please use things that way.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Neil, I'm not sure if this affects anything, but I believe the values are values. They could be any sort of location besides shelf and I need to be able to query upon the keys to retrieve the value.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution which may not be the most elegant, but it works:

myfunction became:

```
def myfunction():
    location = request.form.get('location')
    query = {"tagid": request.form.get('tag')}
    #get document as dictionary:
    retrieve = handle.trackingdb.find_one(query)

    #function replaces values of specified keys in a dict:
    def replace_value(key_to_find, value):
        for key in retrieve.keys():
            if key == key_to_find:
                retrieve[key] = value

    #if the location has changed...:
    if location != retrieve.get("location1", ""):
        #shift all of the key values and insert the new one
        replace_value("location5", retrieve.get("location4", ""))
        replace_value("location4", retrieve.get("location3", ""))
        replace_value("location3", retrieve.get("location2", ""))
        replace_value("location2", retrieve.get("location1", ""))
        replace_value("location1", location)
        #update the document
        tagid = handle.trackingdb.update({},retrieve)
```